# How to tie login screen to laptop monitor

Tags: 22.04

ubuntu 22.04, my laptop has many external monitors, even a TV, when boot the login screen doesn't show on laptop monitor, so I have to open TV to type in password.

Any way to tie login screen to always show on laptop monitor?

Comment: Your answer is not working for me and eshirvana, if you read the comments

Comment: I am sorry it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

## System Settings

Go to the System Settings of your Ubuntu 22.04. You can either search for the **Settings** app or click on the top right corner and find Settings from the drop down menu.

[image]

On the left panel of the Settings window, click on **Displays** as shown above.

You will see all your displays shown in the diagram, as in the picture above. In this picture there are two monitors, called 2, and 1. One is on the right side of 2. Click on the **Down Arrow** next to the **Primary Display ---- `<name of your TV>`**. Then select the laptop's internal display as the primary display.

Hope this helps

Comment: laptop internal display should not be my primary display, I set my 32' 4K external monitor as primary display, to display menu bar and play games. And the login screen is not showing on this 32' 4K monitor, it shows on 60' 4K TV, which is not set as primary monitor

Comment: @LeslieLi This explanation should be in your question. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1433461/edit) and add all this information.

Comment: But login screen is NOT showing on my current primary display, your method should not work

Comment: @LeslieLi once again, please edit your question and add all the information you put in comments above so that someone else can provide a better answer. I will leave my answer here as apparently it helped some other people, as seen by the up votes.

Comment: @LeslieLi did you figure this out? my login won't show up on my primary monitor ( external monitor) and always show up on my laptop monitor

Comment: @eshirvana I set ubuntu to autologin as workaround