# Booting to HDMI Display

Tags: boot, display, hdmi

One of the annoyances of getting older is having to use reading glasses that don't always have the depth of field you need and this is one I cant figure out the best way to solve. *As Spiderman said "With great age comes arthritis in your right knee and having to get up to pee in the night"*

I have Ubuntu 22.04.1 on my laptop. When I am "home" I usually just plug in the USB and the HDMI cables to "dock it" on boot, everything is detected and works right, its just it defaults to running both displays with the logon prompt on my laptop screen and what I really want is when its docked to default to the HDMI output, when it isn't docked default to the laptop screen.

Comment: Try changing the "Primary Display" to the external display by going to Settings > Display, while connected to the external display. See [this question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1433461/how-to-tie-login-screen-to-laptop-monitor). This won't help your right knee though.